# Where is Chris Brown from?

Tags: history, hip-hop

Where is Chris Brown, the famous American artist, from? His music genre is R&B and Hip Hop, he sang "With You".

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Brown), Chris Brown is from Tappahannock, Virginia, U.S.A.